# How do I convert this nested arrays in PHP Code to c#

Tags: c#, php, json

What would be the c# equivalen of this php code?
I am confused as the the array members would be dynamically supplied?

```
?php
 
$messages = array(
    'sender' => "SampleName",
    'messages' => array(
        array(
            'number' => 918123456789,
            'text' => rawurlencode('This is your message')
        ),
        array(
            'number' => 918987654321,
            'text' => rawurlencode('This is another message')
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: If the key names are not dynamic use an anonymous type, otherwise a Dictionary<string, object>.

Answer (score 0):

Would the below be what you expect?

```
public class Messages
{
   public string sender { get; set; }
   public List<ArrayObject> messages { get; set; }
}

public class ArrayObject
{
   public int number { get; set; }
   public string text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `number` should be `long`, as OP numbers are bigger than `int.Max`